# Android BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException only for API 31 above

Tags: java, android, exception, mobile, error-handling

How to catch BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException exception that is supported only after API level 31 above. Basically my code is like this, I also want to support device running API below 31.

```
try {
    context.startService(service);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply add a check for the Exception class name in `IllegalStateException`. As `BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException` is a child class of `IllegalStateException` the exception will end up there:

```
try {
    context.startService(service);
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    if (e.getClass().getName().equals("android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException") {
        // handle BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException
    }
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```